# Spring Batch: ReadListener afterRead gets called even when the reader returns null

Tags: spring-batch

As far as I understand, the reader is supposed to return 'null' if there are no more items to be read, indicating 'end-of-read'. If that is the contract for reader, I assumed the framework would understand this 'null' and will not call 'afterRead' of ReadListener. However, it seems to be calling 'afterRead' with 'null' parameter.

We are using spring-batch 2.1.7. Please let us know if this is expected behavior or is there something that I'm missing here.

The following is the job configuration we have:

```
<batch:job id="job">
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="jobExecutionListener"></batch:listener>
    </batch:listeners>
    <batch:step id="myStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:listeners>
              <batch:listener ref="myReadListener" />
              <batch:listener ref="myTransformerListener" />
              <batch:listener ref="myWriteListener" />
            </batch:listeners>
            <batch:chunk reader="myReader" processor="myTransformer"
                writer="myWriter" commit-interval="1000" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, this is  correct.
Null is the ending value, but it is a read value.

As a consequence, afterReading is executed with a null and your code have to deal with this.